# OpenSSL "wrong curve" error on opnvpn 2.4.8

Tags: openvpn, openssl

I am trying to update our openvpn server to 2.4.8 to take advantage of larger listen() backlog queue. However, we see following errors:

```
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 VERIFY OK: depth=4, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX, OU=Dev, CN=DevEnvironmentL1RootCA
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 VERIFY OK: depth=3, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, CN=DevEnvironmentL2IntermediateCA, O=XXXXX Inc.
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 VERIFY OK: depth=2, ST=CA, CN=DevEnvironmentL3IssuingCA, C=US, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX Inc.
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX, CN=org338.XXXXX.com
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=OPHQ, OU=Q, CN=acu212.org338.dev.XXXXX.local
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 OpenSSL: error:1414D17A:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong curve
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:56176 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 VERIFY OK: depth=4, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX, OU=Dev, CN=DevEnvironmentL1RootCA
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 VERIFY OK: depth=3, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, CN=DevEnvironmentL2IntermediateCA, O=XXXXX Inc.
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 VERIFY OK: depth=2, ST=CA, CN=DevEnvironmentL3IssuingCA, C=US, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX Inc.
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=XXXXX, CN=org343.XXXXX.com
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=OPHQ, OU=Q, CN=acu33.org343.dev.XXXXX.local
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 OpenSSL: error:1414D17A:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong curve
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Mar  6 00:18:06 nebula ovpn-nebula[8220]: 1.1.1.1:45484 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

The cert chain include both ECDSA (with prime256v1 curves) and RSA keys and certs.

We do not see any errors when we downgrade it to openvpn 2.4.7 or any earlier versions.

The dynamically linked libraries for 2.4.7 and 2.4.8 looks identical:

for 2.4.7:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/openvpn
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcce786000)
    liblzo2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2 (0x00007ff8dd406000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007ff8dd1ea000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff8dcfcb000)
    libpkcs11-helper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpkcs11-helper.so.1 (0x00007ff8dcdb0000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007ff8dc8e5000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007ff8dc658000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007ff8dc3d4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff8dc1d0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff8dbddf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff8dd8ed000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff8dbbd7000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff8db9b1000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007ff8db695000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007ff8db480000)
```

for 2.4.8:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/openvpn
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe33adf000)
    liblzo2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2 (0x00007f272d11b000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f272ceff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f272cce0000)
    libpkcs11-helper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpkcs11-helper.so.1 (0x00007f272cac5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f272c5fa000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f272c36d000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f272c0e9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f272bee5000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f272baf4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f272d602000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f272b8ec000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f272b6c6000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f272b3aa000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f272b195000)
```

example server cert:

```
openssl x509 -in crt.pem  -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            aa:ae:4c:ea:bc:48:5b:18:f8:c6:cd:6a:f1:07:2f:61
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = US, ST = CA, L = Los Angeles, O = XXXXX, CN = sandboxEnvironmentL3IssuingCA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 20 00:06:35 2018 GMT
            Not After : Aug 18 00:06:35 2028 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, L = LA, O = OP, OU = G, CN = nebula.sandbox.XXXXX.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:86:b6:99:9b:70:fb:d2:51:5f:4c:f2:d3:f3:cd:
                    e9:f9:d3:33:a3:b9:d4:5d:cc:0d:05:8d:c0:ff:9f:
                    70:fa:ec:c8:a3:e7:0d:1a:d1:5f:24:f3:5f:98:87:
                    43:c7:68:64:00:9d:14:12:a6:2f:87:44:3a:64:59:
                    60:8d:fe:da:52
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.sandbox.XXXX.com/c5e53bbd2876e2b94a66b325ce095c2b.crl

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
                DNS:nebula.sandbox.XXXXX.com
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:64:02:30:5a:77:b9:87:2f:5b:55:e1:76:f5:7d:94:67:d6:
         d8:8f:57:5c:f8:43:97:03:a7:11:2b:be:76:3c:1f:20:01:75:
         c6:3a:ae:8e:db:29:c2:fa:f4:07:37:51:95:dd:2b:42:02:30:
         21:59:34:ca:87:35:7e:88:39:40:eb:43:50:9c:d3:1c:8d:c5:
         22:88:c4:de:b4:0a:80:48:82:d9:c9:0e:34:95:62:2d:64:42:
         6e:29:cc:54:6a:0f:12:10:24:39:ea:b7
```

And example client cert:

```
$ openssl x509 -in crt.pem  -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            a1:52:3a:0b:29:72:8b:43:68:b2:10:8e:35:c8:15:91
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
        Issuer: C = US, ST = CA, L = Los Angeles, O = XXXX, CN = org302.XXXXX.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 27 22:49:40 2019 GMT
            Not After : Nov 16 22:49:40 2021 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, L = Los Angeles, O = OPHQ, OU = Q, CN = xxx443.org302.XXXX.local
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:2f:9e:6e:e5:b4:62:a3:fa:57:4c:15:dd:ac:08:
                    bd:eb:fb:1c:36:09:af:f0:5c:69:2d:9d:b3:a1:61:
                    59:6d:f8:8e:09:a0:72:e5:12:54:33:db:2a:fe:1b:
                    c0:5e:24:b8:20:92:07:d1:8d:6f:3a:73:6d:56:de:
                    b6:2f:03:5a:1e
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.prod.XXXX.com/c49c8c7872647cd6ee67d30f19341a68.crl

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
                DNS:xxx443.org302.XXX.local, DNS:*.xxx443.org302.XXXX.local
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA384
         30:65:02:31:00:9a:81:c4:e1:c5:38:48:94:89:a9:c1:96:93:
         1e:57:75:18:5b:04:ed:c9:c8:41:a4:a4:d5:ee:3a:36:98:fc:
         af:15:09:d4:b8:a3:be:2b:61:00:b2:55:1a:77:46:32:4d:02:
         30:45:63:43:9f:f8:f8:72:e0:f6:94:c8:10:1b:ac:aa:9c:22:
         62:00:0b:14:16:6e:20:1a:cd:1c:a2:c3:85:d7:6d:b8:ff:c0:
         d5:93:0e:87:a2:1f:d9:99:48:eb:83:6b:31
```

Comment: It would be interesting, if you could increase the verbosity level and log the cipher suites exchanged in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an OpenVPN problem, so much as an OpenSSL one (and arguably, it isn't even a *problem* in OpenSSL, more a decision not to support bad ideas any more).  I think [this issue](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/7045) covers it best, and basically it comes down to "stop using explicit curve parameters in your certificates; they were [never a good idea](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-0601) and we're not going to support them any more".

As to why you're seeing these with OpenVPN 2.4.8, and not with earlier versions, I'd guess (and it's all it can be, since you haven't given enough information to tell for sure) that your earlier versions of OpenVPN are built against OpenSSL 1.0.2, which did (try to) support explicit parameters, while support for them was ripped out in the 1.1.0 series.

Comment: That makes sense, but the openssl version that is linked to openvpn is 1.1 for 2.4.7 and 2.4.8. (I added the details to the original question)

Comment: Besides, our certificates does not have any explicit curve parameters in them. It only includes the curve name. (I added that to the question as well)